# PHP fails to connect to postgres and pg_last_error returns an empty string

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm using this to connect to a PostgreSQL database with PHP 7.3.   The connection fails, but the error message is empty. How can I see the error?

```
$sConn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=postgres password=mypassword ";
    
    
    $db = pg_connect($sConn_string);
    
    if (!$db)
    {
        echo "Error 0: " . pg_last_error();
    }
```

pg_result_error() also gives me an empty message.

Comment: I found a connection error in the postgresql log.  But it'd be nice to be able to get that in PHP.

Comment: See the docs [Basic usage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.examples-basic.php). Don't know PHP that well, but I'm going to say `if (!$db)` resolves to False as `$db` is actually set even if there is a connection error.

Comment: try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost - also what is the error received?

Comment: There was no password for postgres. So I fixed the error by setting one. But it'd be nice to be able to see what the error was in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, `pg_last_error()` requires the connection to be established. `pg_result_error()` only works on query results.

You can use [`error_get_last()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) instead

```
$sConn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=postgres password=mypassword";

$db = pg_connect($sConn_string);

if (!$db)
{
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo "Error: " . $error['message'];
}
```